# how to read tables from a text file by python

Tags: python, sql, database

I've download a db version file from [AG's news](http://www.di.unipi.it/~gulli/AG_corpus_of_news_articles.html)

As you can see from the website,data in this file was organized by tables.
And I want to read the title and description from the file. I've tried the pandas and sqlites3,the first one raise an Error:`ValueError: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 124`,and the second one when I execute the sql  statement:`show tables`,it throws an syntax error:`OperationalError: near "show": syntax error`.
I'm a newer in database,could you point out what's wrong with those method or provide me a method to read those tables? Thank in advance!

Comment: What python code have you tried?

Comment: I used pandas as follow:`pa.read_csv(filename)`,and use the sqlite:`conn =sqlite3.connect(filename) c = conn.cursor() c.execute('show tables')`

Comment: What type of database is the `.db` file? `show tables` may not be a valid command in that particilar DBMS

Comment: The file didn't have a suffix,and I don't know which type of database it is.I've tried `select name from sysobjects where type=’U’`,and it throw an exception:`DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database`. It seems this file isn't a database file.You can see details of this file in hyperlink[http://www.di.unipi.it/~gulli/AG_corpus_of_news_articles.html].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `db` file you talk of isn't a database file at all. It is a plain text file which can be opened with a text editor which can handle large files.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion.Thanks a lot !